# "Expression cannot seek vector iterator after end "

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to make a very simple memory game and i'm having the following problem with vectors.
[Expression cannot seek vector iterator after end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Msalk.png)
here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

void play();
void filler();
char faceup(int);

vector<char> cards (50);
int candy= 0;

int main()
{
    filler();
    play();
}
char faceup(int C) {
    return cards[C];
}
void play() {
    int n,l;
    char p, s;
    for (int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << cards[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    while (candy<50)
    {
        cout << "choose first card"<<endl;
        cin >> n;
        cout << "choose second card"<<endl;
        cin >> l;
        if (l == n) {
            cout << "the cards are the same, try it again"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            p = faceup(n);
            s = faceup(l);
            cout << "The first card is: " + p;
            cout << "The second card is: " + s;
            if (s==p)
            {
                candy++;
                cards.erase(cards.begin()+s);
                cards.erase(cards.begin() + p);
            }
        }
    }
}
void filler() {
    //random_device rd;
    //default_random_engine rng(rd());
    int accountant = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < cards.size()/2; i++)
    {
        for (int o = 0; o < 2; o++) {
            cards[accountant] = i+65;
            accountant++;
        }
    }
    //shuffle(cards.begin(), cards.end(), rng);
}
```

the error occurs with any integer that I type. I used the compiler of visual studio, then i used dev c++. In all cases I got the same or similar error

Thanks a million in advance

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve]. In particular, remove manual input unless that is actually necessary to reproduce the problem. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this code, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for and if you don't know how to use it, this is a good opportunity to learn running your program one line at a time in a debugger, monitoring all variables and their values as they change and analysing your program's logic and execution. It should be possible for you to use your debugger to find all simple problems in this and all future programs you write, all by yourself.

Comment: `cout << "The first card is: " + p;` should be `cout << "The first card is: " << p;`. Adding a `char` to a string literal does not append the character to it, but adds the ascii value to it

Comment: Global variables are a bad habit. If you need multiple functions to get access to a variable, pass it as an argument. All upper-case are usually used for macros, using them for variables will be confusing to most programmers. And you have no bounds-checking or other validation of your input.

Comment: A hint: The `cards` vector will be filled with values starting at `65` and then go up. These values will not be possible to use as indexes for the vector itself, and when added to the `begin()` iterator will point out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, in line 11, you defined a vector whose length is equal to 50, and if we give our vector a number outside the numbers 0 to 49, the program should not run.
That you encountered the error I mentioned above in lines 48 and 49 of your program.
For example, if the user enters his card number 0 and 1, the sizes s and p are equal to 66, and lines 48 and 49 say to go to our vector index 66, which creates a problem for running our program.

```
enter code here
             //////////error/////////////////////////
            cards.erase(cards.begin()+s);
            cards.erase(cards.begin() + p);
             //////////error/////////////////////////
```